# Removing location updates using FusedLocationApi NOT working

Tags: android, geolocation, location, fusedlocationproviderapi, location-services

hello Im trying to stop location updates and I have used this code:-

```
LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this)
```

But later I've noticed they stop using "FusedLocationApi" because its kinda deprecated.
So guys, how can i stop location updates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In newer Google place Services FusedLocationApi is deprecated.
And what i understand from your question that you want remove location, so in your case i think this the way to do it:

```
mFusedLocationClient.removeLocationUpdates(mLocationCallback);
```